# What are the requirement to gain experience in Guild Wars 2 when killing a mob?

Tags: guild-wars-2

What makes me gain experience when I kill a mob? Sometimes I try to help other players and when I kill a mob and I gain nothing. Why? Should I engage the fight? Is there a minimum damage? What is the rule?

Answer (score 4):

I found my answer [here](http://keithengel.hubpages.com/hub/Guild-Wars-2-About-Social-Interactivity)

"Furthermore, unlike even games with mob tagging and forced grouping, both players will receive loot from the mob all based on a separate loot table as well.

There is no mob stealing, there is no loot stealing, both players receive a reward, both players receive experience, and both get credit towards quest fulfillment.

It should be noted of course that this mechanic will have a limit in place. This limit will be that if a mob is below a certain threshold of health and near death, than the player that helps will not be rewarded."

Comment: It would be nice knowing what that "certain threshold" is exactly

Comment: From my experience, it seems to be fairly tolerant -- as long as I hit the mob at least once I seem to get XP when the monster dies, as well as a chance for loot.