# Do summoned "allies" damage count towards the threshold for experience and loot?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In this question: [What are the requirement to gain experience in Guild Wars 2 when killing a mob?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/82225/16007), I learned that there is a threshold damage you need to deal to a monster to get experience and a chance at loot from that monster.

I was curious if summoned "allies" damage count towards this. Some example are:

- The ghostly weapons that the guardians can summon
- The snow wurm which is a norn only skill.
- Mistfire Wolf that can be summon by everyone who bought the Digital Deluxe and above.
- Parrots that have 5% chance of being summon with the Superior Rune of the Pirates.

There are a bunch of other summons. I find that they sometimes stray and attack their own targets, particular the parrot. If i did not hit the monster with any of my weapon skills but the monster was killed or assisted by my summon allies, do I gain experience or have a chance of getting loot?

Perhaps the allies summoned from slot skills are treated differently from the allies summon by runes. The parrots that are summon by the pirate runes are surprisingly strong and can take down a regular level 80 monster by itself. I don't believe (but I could be wrong) that I am receiving any experience from that. Nor have I yet to receive loot from it.

Comment: Snow wurm must be racial as I'm Norn Ranger and have this skill :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any damage dealt by summoned allies or pets counts as damage that you've dealt for the sake of experience and loot. So, yes, they do count towards the threshold.

Answer (score 0):

As an engineer, I have had turrets drop mobs and I have gained experience without having hit the mobs myself.

If you are hit with a rocket turrent in PvP/WvW/etc the burning condition will have a source (in PvE, regeneration should show a player source, too).  I am under the impression that summons (like turrets) still list the player as the source of the damage - including against NPCs for final rewards/looting privileges.

The same rules seem to apply for other damage sources - poison wells, fire walls, etc.  A mob could walk through any of these damage sources before dying and you should still get credit as long as the damage is higher than the threshold you mention.

Comment: Poison wells and fire walls are completely different from summon allies.

Comment: Have you had any experience with allies summoned from runes? The parrots that the pirate rune summons are surprisingly strong. They can take down a regular lvl 80 monster by itself and I don't think I am getting any exp from that and have yet to receive loot from those kills.

Comment: I understand poison wells and fire walls may be different from allies. :)  Just added it since it had the common "source" ID just like "critters."

I have not tried the parrots - only the turrets and the summoned Golem from the Engineers Elite Skill.  I can try the Golem later tonight.

Comment: Just tried with the Golem - got XP and loot.

Comment: @esnyder any idea if summoned Thieves count? I've seen mine run off and kill a few random enemies but haven't noticed any xp

Comment: I can try to confirm later, Alex.  I want to say yes - I ran around Hirathi Hinterlands with summoned thieves and daggers.  The thieves would normally run ranged attacks and I remember getting xp.

Will try to get some sigils with parrots - sorry, I forgot over the weekend.

Comment: The thieves seem to not always award xp or loot chance.  I think I got XP and loot more often than not, but there were differently a few questionable kills with no XP reward...